# No mr job execution info in beeline

Tags: hive, beeline, hiveserver2

In beeline, I could not see the job execution info (like job progress), I have already set the following properties in hive-site.xml. Could anyone help to figure out how to diagnose such issues ? How can I check whether hive server2 take the correct configuration ?

```
hive.server2.logging.operation.level VERBOSE
```

I only see the following log in beeline

```
WARNING: Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try
set hive.root.logger=INFO,console;

Answer (score 0):

I forget to set `hive.async.log.enabled` to be `false`, after this setting it works